# how to add a json object to a request string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to send a json formatted string as a hidden field for a form.

I get the data as follows:

```
 $.getJSON(email_url,function(fb){
                var pic_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+fb.id+"/picture";
                json_details.push({name: fb.name, fbuid: fb.id, picUrl: pic_url, birthday: fb.birthday }); 
                var manager_details = JSON.parse(json_details);
 html += "<form id='new_celebration"+fb.id+"' method='post' action='/celebrations' accept-charset='UTF-8'>";
html += "<input type='hidden' id='manager' value='"+manager_details +"'  name='celebration[manager_details]' />"
 html += "</form>";

$('.facebookfeed').html(html);
              });
```

But if I add it this way I get extra "\".

How can I add the json object to the request string so I can send this data in with the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you'll want to do this:

```
manager_details = escape(JSON.stringify(json_details));

...

html += "<input type='hidden' id='manager' value='"+manager_details +"'  name='celebration[manager_details]' />"
```

JSON.stringify converts your JSON object to string. [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) sets up your value to be sent as a URL parameter, which is what will happen since your [form content-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) is not set to multipart/form-data; this will also remove the '\' that you're referring to.

Comment: oops.. Accidentally wrote 'encode' at first instead of 'escape'.

Comment: Hi JP I tried the escape(JSON.stringify(json_details)); and I get '%' everywhere => value="%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Mitchell%20Gould%22%2C%22fbuid%22%3A%22751640040%22%2C%22picUrl%22%3A%22http%3A//graph.facebook.com/751640040/picture%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%2210/07/1967%22%7D%5D"> what am I doing wrong?

Comment: On your server side, you must unescape it. What's your server side language?

Comment: Ruby. So its ok to have the '%'?

Comment: Yes. So on your ruby side, do this: my_hash = JSON.parse(URI.unencode(YOUR_SERVER_VAR)) Then you can access your data like: my_hash[:fbuid] etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want JSON.stringify, not parse.

If I could zoom out a bit for a couple of suggestions, though:

- Why not have the form elements already existing on your page, and do something like `$('#manager').val(manager_details);` instead of generating the HTML in JS? In general, it's good practice to avoid creating HTML strings in your JS if possible (separation of concerns and all that)
- If you're already using JS, why not skip the hidden field entirely and simply attach the data on form submission? Meaning, you already have your data in `manager_details`, so on from `submit`, do a `$.post()` and include `manager_details` in your data.

Comment: Hi Phillip, the reason I am doing it this way is I get FB user friend's info and put it on a page. Each friend will have a form associated with their info. The user then selects the friend and I send the info to the server. So I can't put the form on the page before as I have one form for each friend.  Your second point it good I could attach an event to the click or submit function of the form and then add the manager details. I still have the issue of hidden fields for the friends data which I want to include in a json object or the like

Comment: You'll have to watch out for duplicate IDs, then. Just my opinion, but I think you'll end up with cleaner code if you keep your data in JS rather than in a hidden field (my second suggestion), esp since you'll have multiple friends. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also base64 encode the stringified json_details object.

That way you're sure it won't have any problems when being sent to the server .

**Edit**

Have a look at : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

And for encoding in js just use google : http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html this is the first hit.

Comment: Hi sirocco I would like to look at this. How to I base64 encode an object?